# Function returns null pointer instead of address

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, storage

I'm playing around with pointers to understand this concept better
and wanted to ask

Why do i get null pointer as return for the second function?

and why it isn't possible to get the address 0x7fff15504044. 
What is happening and where inside memory is the integer 5 stored,
when im working with it inside the function?.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* return_adress(int* input){ return input; }

int* return_adress_from_input(int input){ return &input; }

int main(){
    int k = 3; 
    cout << return_adress(&k) << endl;
    cout << return_adress_from_input(k) << endl;
}
```

Output:

0x7fff15504044

0

Comment: Because it's undefined behavior. Also open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how parameters are passed by value.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: You probably want to take `input` by reference and not by value: `int input` =>`int& input`

Comment: @AMA: Then the OP would be advised to change the return type to `const int*`.

Comment: @Bathsheba fixed while you were typing :)

Comment: @AMA: If I continue to type, will you fix the bugs in my code too ;-) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `int* return_adress_from_input(int input)`, `input` is a value copy of `k` in the caller. They are two different variables therefore with different addresses.

`input` goes out of scope conceptually once the closing brace of the function is reached.

The pointer `&input` then points to memory that you no longer own, and the behaviour of reading that pointer value (let alone dereferencing it) is *undefined* prior to C++14, and *implementation defined* from and including C++14.

Comment: It's implementation defined since C++14

Comment: @PasserBy: So it is: which accounts for the `nullptr` value.

Answer (score 1):

Because you pass `input` by value, not by reference. Compiller first creates a local copy of `input` and then returns address of this local copy. To get the variable address use

```
int* return_adress_from_input(int& input){ return &input; }
```

In general, you get undefined behavior which can lead to returning `nullptr` in the particular case

On my PC i get

```
00AFFC80
00AFFBA8
```

so you are just lucky with zero return